# Certificate with 1024 bit key performing a SHA2 signing

Tags: certificate, ssl-certificate

My current setup is I have an intermediate CA with a 1024 bit RSA key.
I will be utilising this intermediate CA to sign client certificates in my enterprise, I wish to give these certificates a SHA2 RSA signature.
A colleague advised that using a 1024 bit private key to perform a SHA2 RSA signature isn't possible. 
However I can't seem to find any documentation online concerning this.
Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1024-bit RSA can do SHA-256 signatures with both PKCS#1v1.5 padding and PSS padding.

PSS padding requires `2 * hashSize + 2` bytes, or `2 * hashSize + 16` bits. So for a SHA-256 signature (256 bit output) the minimum RSA keysize is 512+16 => 528-bit.

PKCS#1 v1.5 signature padding requires a minimum of `tLen + 11` bytes, where `tLen` is the hash size (in bytes) plus a fixed overhead that differs based on the algorithm (`tLen` is the length of `T`, the DER-encoded DigestInfo containing the hash). For SHA-256 `tLen` is 51, so the minimum key size is (51 + 11) * 8 => (62 * 8) => 496-bit.

#### Security Considerations:

496-bit and 528-bit are both considered atrociously low in 2019.

1024-bit is also considered to be on the low side of the scale (it provides roughly 80 bits of security).

[NIST SP 800-57 Part 3](https://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/SpecialPublications/NIST.SP.800-57Pt3r1.pdf) recommends RSA-2048 for CA operations.